# Overriding not working Codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create a role based system so i found this tutorial online :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOzmO61CsVg&t=619s

so i started creating the Controllers by watching the videos.

after i created MY_Controller class I extended the Page Class to MY_Controller class and override the `$access` variable to check whether it is working or not, I tried to print the `$access` variable in MY_Controller Class

but it is always giving * when i do die, may be i am doing something wrong.

below is the code :

**MY_Controller Class :**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

/**
* '*' all user
* '@' logged in user
* 'Hospital' for hospital users
* 'Reciever' for recievers
* @var string
*/

private $access = "*";

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->login_check();
}

public function login_check(){
    if ($this->access != "*") 
    {
        // here we check the role of the user
        if (! $this->permission_check()) {
            die("<h4>Access denied</h4>");
        } 

        // if user try to access logged in page
        // check does he/she has logged in
        // if not, redirect to login page
        if (! $this->session->userdata("logged_in")) {
            redirect("auth");
        }
    }


    die($this->access);
}



    public function permission_check(){
        if ($this->access == "@") {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $access = is_array($this->access) ? 
                $this->access :
                explode(",", $this->access);
            if (in_array($this->session->userdata("role"), array_map("trim", $access)) ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Pages Class :**

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller {

    protected $access="Admin";

    public function view($page='available_samples') {

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $page;

        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**What i am getting**

i am getting `$access` variable value as * always.

**Expected Behaviour**

the value of `$access` variable in Pages class should override the access variable value in the MY_Controller class.

Comment: what error are you getting. its too brief. add expected result or behaviour in question. that helps alot.

Comment: ok I have edited the question